# How to create an android library and upload it on github?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have created a new module in Android Studio, and wrote my code in it. Now i want to upload it on github and get a gradle dependency which others can include in their project and use my library. How can i get it?

PS. I know how to use git, i just don't know how to upload just the library module and get the gradle dependency.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The esiest way is to create a git repository in Github and upload it there.

After that, you can use [jitpack.io](https://jitpack.io/) to use it with gradle.

[The long old way](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en), it is to create a [Bintray](https://bintray.com/) project, and deploy it at MavenCentral and/or JCentre.

Answer (score 1):

What do you need to do is upload your project to [Bintray](https://bintray.com/) or [sonatype](http://sonatype.org)

See here a good tutorial:

[how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en)